# Checking compositeness of n given n is odd.

Tags: number-theory, factoring, cryptography

> Suppose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is odd and $$ 2^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \equiv k \mod n,$$
>   where $k \neq \pm1$. Show that $n$ is composite.

*My work:*

I got this far and get stuck:

Basically I took the square root of both sides and now have

$$ 2^{n-1} \equiv k^{2} \mod n .$$
If $k$ is prime, then LHS would be 1 by Fermat's little theorem, so $k^{2} \equiv 1 \mod n$

SO now I'm stuck; is it something to do with the fact that $k^{2}$ cant be $1$, because $k$ only would have one multiplicative inverse ($\mod n$) if $n$ were prime?

Comment: I've improved the formatting of your post. Could you perhaps consider removing or changing the opening paragraph? "I'm trying... here goes". In general, everyone here is trying and nobody is mean - those things should be taken for granted.

Comment: Okay, thanks. May I have a link to a good place to get formatting tips/tricks?

Comment: Your argument is nearly complete.  Suppose $n$ were prime.  Then you have correctly argued that the square of your number is $1\pmod n$, so, again since $n$ is prime, that would force your number to be $\pm 1$.

Comment: Absolutley, [here is a post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) with lots of help

Comment: Note:  There really isn't a good notion of absolute value $\pmod n$.  Better to just say $k\neq \pm 1$.

Comment: I think I see my error. Instead of saying "if k is prime", I will say "if n is prime" then LHS is 1, and since RHS is a square it follows that it not be be it's own multiplicative inverse (mod n) without being 1 or -1.

Answer (score 1):

$n$ odd prime $\Rightarrow 2^{n-1} \equiv 1  \mod n \Rightarrow k^2 \equiv 1 \mod n \Rightarrow k \equiv \pm1 \mod n.$